# Is there a fix for intermittent "[app name] succesfully updated" notifications?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar

It's not a big deal, but I'd like to know if someone has figured out the logic behind the disappearing update notifications?

For example, recently I set 10 apps to be updated and kept the Play Store app active (no screen timeout or anything). After the apps had been updated I saw only 3 notifications, even though all the apps appear to have been updated. The same has happened almost every time I update multiple applications.

I'd understand it if there was only one notification, or as many as updates, but the number is seemingly random.

I've seen this on my Galaxy Nexus on both 4.0.1 and 4.0.2.

Comment: Uhmmm not sure what is the problem? Developers update the app, upload it, if there's permission changes made to the said app, it reverts from auto to manual update to enable you to check it out first... am I missing something here?

Comment: I meant the notifications after the update. If I have tens of updates I like the possibility to set them to update and check them later, after they're downloaded&updated. Now that the notifications disappear, I have to write down the updated apps to remember which to check.

Answer (score 2):

I see what you're saying... one way around it, is to look in the logcat and keep an eye out for something like the following, in this case, I downloaded an app called Rendezvous, this is what appears in the logcat

```
D/PackageManager(  242): Scanning package com.jgms.rendezvous
I/PackageManager(  242): Package com.jgms.rendezvous codePath changed from /data/app/com.jgms.rendezvous-1.apk to /data/app/com.jgms.rendezvous-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
I/PackageManager(  242): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.jgms.rendezvous-2.apk
D/installd(  120): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.jgms.rendezvous-2.apk' ---
D/dalvikvm(23670): creating instr width table
D/dalvikvm(23670): DexOpt: load 22ms, verify+opt 203ms
D/installd(  120): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.jgms.rendezvous-2.apk' (success) ---
D/PackageManager(  242):   Activities: com.jgms.rendezvous.login com.jgms.rendezvous.MakeWaypoint com.jgms.rendezvous.FindExisting com.jgms.rendezvous.ShareLocation com.jgms.rendezvous.FindFriend com.jgms.rendezvous.ShowMap com.jgms.rendezvous.About
I/ActivityManager(  242): Force stopping package com.jgms.rendezvous uid=10202
W/PackageManager(  242): Code path for pkg : com.jgms.rendezvous changing from /data/app/com.jgms.rendezvous-1.apk to /data/app/com.jgms.rendezvous-2.apk
W/PackageManager(  242): Resource path for pkg : com.jgms.rendezvous changing from /data/app/com.jgms.rendezvous-1.apk to /data/app/com.jgms.rendezvous-2.apk
I/installd(  120): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.jgms.rendezvous-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.jgms.rendezvous-2.apk@classes.dex
D/PackageManager(  242): New package installed in /data/app/com.jgms.rendezvous-2.apk
```

Notice the last line, "*New package installed....*"

If there's any other way, I'd gladly amend this :)

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that it shows up in the log... Maybe I'll whip up an app for tracking updates :) Thanks for the info!

Comment: @onik I'm pretty sure that there's an intent that fires when an app is installed/updated.

Comment: PACKAGE_ADDED, PACKAGE_REMOVED iirc top of my head :)